# Android Time.format("%a") giving incorrect day of the week

Tags: android, strftime

I'm trying to retrieve the localized day for a given timestamp. My code is something like this

```
String timestamp = "2011-08-01T15:55:03.000+02:00";
Time time = new Time();
time.parse3339(timestamp);
// In strftime format "%a" should be the abbreviated weekday name
// according to the current locale.
String result = time.format("%a")
```

Since the 1st of Aug. 2011 is a Monday the result String should be "Mon" (assuming English locale), but instead it is "Sun"!

Comment: Is it possible the parse3339 failed? Could you be seeing a 'zero'? Try setting the date ahead one and see if its 'mon'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

time.normalize() must be called, otherwise the values for weekDay, yearDay, isDst and gmtoff will all be 0.

The correct code is:

```
time.parse3339(timestamp);
time.normalize(false);
String localizedDayOfWeek = time.format("%a")
```

Thanks to Femi, who put me on the right track by pointing out that in certain cases the time may be converted to UTC by time.parse3339().

Comment: Thanks this just helped me. Everything was coming back Sunday. Now if i normalize after each date change it works

Answer (score 1):

You should check the return value: from the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#parse3339%28java.lang.String%29):

`Returns true if the resulting time value is in UTC time.`

If the parse returned a UTC time that falls on Sunday you might get this. Not sure how that would be possible given your example above, but I can't think of anything else that would do this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to parse the given timestamp, or would you like to get date now? In the case of the latter, use:

```
Time time = new Time();
time.setToNow();
String result = time.format("%a");
```